# Devise_Invitable spec redirects to '/users/sign_in' on a selenium/capybara spec

Tags: selenium, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, devise-invitable

Im using **capybara/rspec/selenium/devise_invitable** on rails 3.2

See this spec, it invites the user and mails the invitation url. Im extracting the invitation_token from the email body and trying to visit the accept invitation url like below. ('/users/invitation/accept?' + inv_token )

**FYI: it works if I dont set :js => true**

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe "LoginSpec" do
    it "Click enquiries tabs", :js => true do 
        build(:user) do |user|
                user.invite!
                last_email.to.should include(user.email)
                inv_url = Capybara.string(last_email.body.encoded).first(".inbox > a")[:href]
                inv_token = inv_url.split("?")[1]
                inv_url_final = '/users/invitation/accept?' + inv_token   
                visit inv_url_final
        end
    end
    end
```

**But this redirects to '/users/sign_in' all the time.** Here is the test log.

```
Started GET "/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=Ww-y2QbgsswZCgovAzWx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 04:47:14 +0530
    Processing by Users::InvitationsController#edit as HTML
      Parameters: {"invitation_token"=>"Ww-y2QbgsswZCgovAzWx"}
      [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`invitation_token` = 'e75e32adac5414243930d19e927c8a6275c404b8296757e77dc4a49b2593882a' LIMIT 1[0m
      [1m[35mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`invitation_token` = 'Ww-y2QbgsswZCgovAzWx' LIMIT 1
    Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:56113/
    Filter chain halted as :resource_from_invitation_token rendered or redirected
```

**Any help?**

Answer (score 0):

The following in your spec_helper worked, got from
http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

```
 config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```